# How to use HTML5 native validation rules for text input fields in ASP.NET-MVC 5.2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In HTML5 we can create input fields with custom validation error statements. 
For instance:

```
<input type="text" name="username"
       id="username" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{5,}"
       maxlength="30" required />
<div class="validation-messages"> 
     <span data-rule="valueMissing" //FIRST RULE
     class="hide">The username is required. </span>
     <span data-rule="patternMismatch" //SECOND RULE
     class="hide">ust be a series of alpha characters only (min 5, max 30).          
    </span> 
</div>
```

If user breaks any data rule he gets notification which depends on the broken rule and I look for a way to use them in ASP.NET-MVC.

All HTML5 native errors are:`valueMissing`, `typeMismatch`, `patternMismatch`, `tooLong`, `rangeUnderflow`, `stepMismatch`, `value`.

In ASP.NET-MVC the `Html.EditorFor()` method is vastly used. For instance:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

It generates input fields.

Where and how should I define those native validation errors prompts(for instance patternMismatch seen above)? Should I do it in the `EditorFor` method or there is a way to define them in the model class?

Comment: I don't think there is a dynamic way that can generate html validations depending on validations you have set in your model. But I guess templates is one thing you can check .. http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html .. might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate an input against its type, use EditorFor in the view as you have but then in your model decorate the fields with the DataType attribute like so:

```
public class ModelTest 
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

You can then go a step futher and use additional parameters to specify various elements of error detailing such as an error message.

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
```

If you need it to be required use the following attribute

```
[Required]
```

If you need to check string length you can use the following attributes as necessary

```
[StringLength()]
[MinLength()]
[MaxLength()]
```

For number based validation perhaps try

```
[Range()]
```

More often then not, when you are unsure or want to see if some validation exists, just use the Intellisense to browse through possible DataAnnotations

**Additional Reading**

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx

Comment: This is one error message. The HTML5 have these native error messages: `valueMissing`, `typeMismatch`, `patternMismatch`, `tooLong`, `rangeUnderflow`, `stepMismatch`, `value`.

Comment: Thanks. I already know these. The first example in the OP shows custom notification which depends on the broken rule and I look for a way to use them in ASP.NET-MVC.

Comment: I don't understand what you can't achieve using the attributes I have posted or any of the other dataannotations?

Comment: @Glitch100, mvc renders validations using jquery unobtrusive not html5

Comment: I know but when it is rendered to the page it is done by placing restrictions on the model. Conveniently this is then also used for server side

Comment: @Glitch100 You're right I didn't know that MVC uses different technology to  achieve this. There is no reason to preach to the converted.(is it a lame idiom?)